# Displaying Italic Text Using EJS

Tags: angularjs, ejs

In my database I have the following value stored. "What is your *Question*
I am using the EJS syntax to show the text but it is displaying the value as is. It not not converting "Question" into Italic.

I am using the below line of code

```
<%-ask.question%>
```

I am using angularjs is there a way I can leverage that to show the italic value.

Comment: wrap this in <i> or <em> tag.

Comment: @AnujSharma I only want the last part in my text to be italic "Question"

Comment: @charlietfl it is stored in DB with <i>Question</i>

Comment: inspect using dev tools to get the problem.

Comment: angularjs interpolation doesn't accept html. See [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive docs. Note the need for `$sanitize` service

Comment: @charlietfl is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: did you try ng-bind-html?

Comment: @charlietfl yes but it returns empty value I also tried <% ng-bind-html %>

Comment: But that's not how it's used. See examples in docs

Comment: @charlietfl I do not see in document, if you know the fix please let me know

Comment: From link above .. **"Usage"**. Shows two flavors of using it. Also can search in SO for similar https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangularjs%5Dng-bind-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used <%= ask.question %>